# Why a global variable which I assigned the value of a number input tag parsed as a string when I access it inside a function?

Tags: javascript, html, string, numbers

I am a newbie to javascript and I am making a small web calculator with two input tags for numbers. I set the "type" property of the input to "=number" and now I want that when a user clicks on add button, he/she gets the output.
But the problem is that when I declare any variable containing the value(safely enclosed within "parseInt") of the input GLOBALLY, and access that var inside my function, it is getting parsed as a string.(even after using parseInt)

I tried declaring the variable inside the fucntion, and it works fine, I mean it gets parsed a NUMBER only.
But the problem is that I cannot assign the vars repeatedly in evry function for add, sub, divide..etc as the ode will get long and hefty.

Please help me and tell me how can I declare the var GLOBALLY but as a NUMBER...

```js
var value1, value2;
value1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value1").value);
value2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value2").value);

function add() {
  added = value1 + value2;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = added;
}
```

```html
First no:<input type="number" id="value1"><br> Second no:<input type="nunmber" id="value2"><br>

<button onclick="add()">add</button><br> output: <span id="output"></span>
```

Comment: You're retrieving `value1` and `value2` on pageload, when they haven't been inputted yet. Retrieve them inside the handler instead, once the inputs have been populated

Comment: You are not passing the values to your add() function.

Comment: Why do you think *globals* and *strings* have anything to do with the problem?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I didn't get it bro. How do I retrieve them in the handler, once the inputs have been populated?

Comment: @deceze Because apparently, when I declare VARs globally, the output in NaN. But when I declare them inside the function, it works fine, and I don't know why!

Comment: Yes, you got half of that right; it has nothing to do with strings though.

Comment: @Dev.Mehul the reason you were getting NaN was because when you initialised the variables, you grabbed the **empty** input value, and when added them you got NaN. When you got the variables inside of the function, you were grabbing the input values **after** you inputted them, thus letting the code work as normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the variable assignments to inside of the function, so they get set every time the function is set, and so you don't have to pass them from the HTML side:

```js
function add() {
  var value1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value1").value);
  var value2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value2").value);
  var added = value1 + value2;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = added;
}
```

```html
First no:<input type="number" id="value1"><br> Second no:<input type="nunmber" id="value2"><br>

<button onclick="add()">add</button><br> output: <span id="output"></span>
```

EDIT: If you want the variables to be global, you can use an event listener:

```js
var value1, value2;

document.getElementById("value1").addEventListener('input', function (evt) {
    value1 = +evt.target.value
});

document.getElementById("value2").addEventListener('input', function (evt) {
    value2 = +evt.target.value
});


function add() {
  var added = value1 + value2;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = added;
}
```

```html
First no:<input type="number" id="value1"><br> Second no:<input type="nunmber" id="value2"><br>

<button onclick="add()">add</button><br> output: <span id="output"></span>
```

Comment: But if I have like 10 more functions for different arithmetical problems, I would have to declare these variables in every function, would'nt that be lengthy

Comment: You might think it's lengthy, but it isn't in the long run and it works. If you were to leave the variables where you kept them, you would not be able to update or access the new values. If you want a solution for the lengthy code, look into jquery.

Comment: No problem. If you encounter any other issues, let me know, and feel free to mark the answer as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see that solved your problem with global variable.

```js
var value1, value2;


function add() {
  value1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value1").value);
  value2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value2").value);
  if(value1 && value2){
    added = value1 + value2;
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = added;
    checkGlobalVal();
  }else{
    console.log('Please give the input value.');
  }
  
}

function checkGlobalVal(){
  console.log('value1:',value1,' value2:',value2);
}
```

```html
First no:<input type="number" id="value1"><br> Second no:<input type="nunmber" id="value2"><br>

<button onclick="add()">add</button><br> output: <span id="output"></span>
```